# R stop() function not enforced within if else statement

Tags: r

I'm trying to automatically QA some part of my R script with the following:

```
... other R code before...

if( Table1$date==Sys.Date() ){print("Successful check, all good to proceed")
}else{print("Execution stopped. Check Table1");stop()}

... other R code after...
```

In the scenario that the check fails I do see the following message, but the R script proceeds  without stopping as it was expected to behave from the `stop()` command. How may I fix this?

```
[1] "Execution stopped. Check Table1"
Error:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming, that you are running this in an interactive R Session, probably RStudio. In that case when you run the whole file each line is being executed independently of the previous lines succeeding or failing. If you run the script from the operation system command line/ terminal instead, it will break at the `stop()`, when the condition of the `if()` statement is FALSE.

Try this, to see what happens when the condition is FALSE:

```
Rscript -e 'if(FALSE){print("Successful check, all good to proceed"}
else{print("Execution stopped. Check Table1");stop()};a<-1;a'
```

Try this, to see what happens when condition is TRUE:

```
Rscript -e 'if(TRUE){print("Successful check, all good to proceed"}
else{print("Execution stopped. Check Table1");stop()};a<-1;a'
```

To achieve the behaviour you are looking for you could execute your whole file from the operation system command line/ terminal with `Rscript` or [edit:] just move the further code into the if statement

Something like this should work:

```
  if (check_date == Sys.Date()) {
    print("Successful check, all good to proceed")
    # more code here
  } else {
    stop("Execution stopped. Check Table1")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation. I've not realized the difference between running code via IDE vs calling it from OS command line.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would suggest putting in a more reprex code example.

In R, you can wrap your `print` code in the `stop()` function.

```
... other R code before...

if( Table1$date==Sys.Date() ){
    print("Successful check, all good to proceed")
} else {
    stop("Execution stopped. Check Table1")
}

... other R code after...
```

Comment: thank you the error message is displayed in red now, but the rest script still continues with execution..